# Is there a "git hook" command?

Tags: git

When trying to run the command:

```
git p4 submit --shelve
```

(which runs `git-p4.py`) I am getting the error:

```
git: 'hook' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

When I look in the code for `git-p4.py`, I see that it's trying to run the command:

```
git hook run p4-prepare-changelist
```

but, there doesn't seem to really be a command like `git hook`!  The error message says it all! So what is going on?

Comment: git hooks are scripts run on some git events - not a command. Your git has extensive configuration customization so it will be hard for us to help you, since apparently something is wrong with this configuration.

Comment: BTW which operating system you are running? Is there a `git-hook.py` script?

Comment: Why do you say my git "has extensive configuration customization"?  Are you talking about "git p4"?  That is not so "extensive".  That's nothing more than a python script called git-p4.py

Comment: this is "git for windows".  I'm not aware of any `git-hook.py` script.  Maybe that's what I need?

Comment: `p4` is custom command and use of hooks is also customization of git (by default hooks don't do anything). Error is result of missing `git-hook.*` script from l=already custom command. You should contact with person responsible for maintaining this customizations.

Comment: No, `git p4` exists as a command. [Here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4).

Comment: @RomainValeri yest you are right, I get confused since he wrote about script: `git-p4.py` and this kind of script are usually user defined.

Comment: Could it be a `p4-pre-submit` [hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4#_p4_pre_submit) launching and preventing the `p4 submit`?

Comment: There is something fishy with extension, [here is code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-p4.py#L221-L228) which tries run `git hook`. Note there is no `git-hook.*` and there is no build in command like this.

Comment: @JoelFan can you provide details of your git? Based on VonC answer apparently you are a victim of some bug which diverged versions of `git-p4.py` (you have not released version) and version of git.

Comment: See my comment on the answer by VonC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge [`git hook run`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71101716/6309) will only be released with Git 2.36 (Q2 2022).

The [code](https://github.com/git/git/blame/master/git-p4.py#L221-L228) mentioned in the comments has been introduced by [`git/git` commit 0c8ac06](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c8ac06b53cf048dc5aae6f31123e93b62af7cfc), which is also for the next Git release.

> It seems like the only way to get git-p4.py is to copy it from github . The one I have is the latest one from master

That means you need one matching your `git version`
For instance:

https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.35.1/git-p4.py

Comment: So how come he has new version of `git-p4.py` and old git? Is there some silent update of git scripts?

Comment: @MarekR That I do not know, but unless it is used with a freshly compiled Git, said code would not work.

Comment: It seems like the only way to get `git-p4.py` is to copy it from `github` .  The one I have is the latest one from `master` (https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-p4.py).  Should I be using a different branch insetad of `master`?

Comment: @JoelFan Yes, get the version matching your own Git version. For instance https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.35.1/git-p4.py

Comment: @VonC, that fixed it!!!

Comment: @JoelFan Great! I have already edited the answer accordingly.